# OCaml String Removal and Concatenation

Tags: ocaml

The question I have to solve is the following:

Write a function

```ocaml
val newFileName : string -> string -> string;
```

such that a call *`(newFileName oldFileName newExtension)`* returns `oldFileName` but with the new extension.

For example...

1. the call *`(newFileName "MyFileName.java" "class")`* should return the string *`"MyFileName.class"`*. **The input file name may have zero or more dots.**
2. The call *`(newFileName "MyFile" "anything")`* (i.e., with no dots) should return just *`"MyFile"`*;
3. The call *`(newFileName "My.File.java" "class")`* should return *`"My.File.class"`* (i.e., only the rightmost dot matters);
4. The call *`(newFileName "MyFile." "class")`* should return *`"MyFile.class"`*, i.e., a trailing dot with no actual file extension still gives the new extension.

**Hint: Take a look at [`String.rindex_opt`](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/string.ml#L168) in the standard library.**

Here is what I have so far but it's not working:

```
let newFileName old_file new_class = 
  match String.rindex_opt old_file '.' with
  | None -> old_file
  | _ -> let first_part = String.sub old_file 0 (String.rindex old_file '.') in 
      first_part ^ new_class;;
```

Is there anything I could do differently?

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you try it, what does it return right now?

Comment: `String.rindex_opt` is returning the rindex. Why are you discarding and then recalculating this value?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the value from `rindex_opt`.

```
# let replace_extension fn new_ext =
    match String.rindex_opt fn '.' with
    | None -> fn
    | Some ri -> String.sub fn 0 ri ^ "." ^ new_ext;; 
val replace_extension : string -> string -> string = <fun>
# replace_extension "hello.java" "class";;
- : string = "hello.class"
# replace_extension "hello" "class";;
- : string = "hello"
```

You might also use `Format.sprintf`.

```
# let replace_extension fn new_ext =
    match String.rindex_opt fn '.' with
    | None -> fn
    | Some ri -> Format.sprintf "%s.%s" (String.sub fn 0 ri) new_ext;; 
val replace_extension : string -> string -> string = <fun>
# replace_extension "hello.java" "class";;
- : string = "hello.class"
```

We might also use a local binding to clean this up a bit further.

```
let replace_extension fn new_ext =
  match String.rindex_opt fn '.' with
  | None -> fn
  | Some ri -> 
      let name = String.sub fn 0 ri in
      Format.sprintf "%s.%s" name new_ext
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easily done using the OCaml standard library, namely using the [Filename](https://ocaml.org/api/Filename.html) module, e.g.,

```
let change_extension path ext = 
  Filename.remove_extension path ^ "." ^ ext
```